# iText en PDF Java

Tags: java, pdf, itext

Quisiera alinear el título en el centro de la celda pero no detecta la instrucción `ALIGN_CENTER`.

¿Por qué el título no se coloca en el centro?

He importado el JAR **itextpdf-5.5.3**

```
import com.itextpdf.text.*;
```

**Código:**

```
        //Añadimos una tabla de 7 columnas. 
        PdfPTable tabla = new PdfPTable(7); 
        //Porcentaje al ancho de la tabla. 120%.
        tabla.setWidthPercentage(120);
        //Porcentajes del ancho de cada columna.
        tabla.setWidths(new float[] {10, 12, 18, 12, 20, 16, 22});

        //Añadimos los títulos a la tabla. 
        Paragraph columna1 = new Paragraph("DNI");
        columna1.getFont().setStyle(Font.BOLD);
        columna1.getFont().setSize(9);
        columna1.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER); //aquí
        tabla.addCell(columna1);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar otra propiedad:

```
columna1.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
```

Comment: No es una solución correcta. La propiedad TextAlignment no está en la clase Paragraph, y sí Element.